# How to disable non-desktop application notification?

Tags: gnome, notification, dconf

I've just installed `espanso` and I have received some annoying notifications like this:

[image]

Because `espanso` isn't a desktop application so I trying to disable these notifications using `dconf` but I don't see `espanso` in notifications settings as the image below:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the espanso notifications by adding the following option to your `default.yml` config:

```
show_notifications: false
```

([Source](https://espanso.org/docs/configuration/))